# Elastic / responsive image expanding outside current container

Tags: html, css

I was using some code from this (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos) site to have a nice "elastic" video container that would size with my responsive design.

I'm looking to do something similar but with images. So it resizes with the design, keeping the proportions and allow it to expand a bit outside it's current containers' margins.

I think I need to wrap the image in a div and position that somehow but I just need some advice if anyone has done something similar to this. The exact dimensions/etc are not important, just the process behind it. Thanks!

**Here's an image to what I'm looking to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84KvA.gif**

[image: what I want]

Comment: So, when you resize the window, the width of the image increases a little bit more than the width of the outer container (while the image margin decreases), until image width is 100% and image margin is 0px?

I very much doubt this can be done in pure CSS, but should be doable with javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's kind of hard to visualize. Think of the post container (gray) having 30px of padding. I can suck -30px of margin off the top and left to move the image (relative positioning) but then I don't know how to stretch it across to the other side. Sorry for the poor example(s)... not even sure how to word this.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
img {
  max-width: 110%;
  margin: 0 -5%;
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot but I think I'm going to have to re-think my entire idea now that I see it in writing. :( Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, I decided to break the image out from the content, I'll add fake classes to help explain what I did...

```
<div class='no-longer-padded-post-element'>

<img src="now-can-span-full-width.jpg" />

    <div class='content-with-padding'>
       title
       content
       meta
       etc.
    </div>

</div>
```